# Make sure that method returns a List<String> and not just a List. in java

Tags: java, type-mismatch

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    idList.add(0,"a");
    idList.add(1,"b");
    idList.add(2,"c");
    for (String uuid : idList) {
      System.out.println(uuid);
    }
  }
```

In "uuid : idList"

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String"

What's wrong?

Comment: You're using a raw type. Use `ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define type of your array so you can't use `foreach` in this way.

you can do this (define the type):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    idList.add(0,"a");
    idList.add(1, "b");
    idList.add(2, "c");
    for (String uuid : idList) {
      System.out.println(uuid);
    }

}
```

or (use `foreach` on `Object` not `String`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList idList = new ArrayList<String>();
    idList.add(0,"a");
    idList.add(1, "b");
    idList.add(2, "c");
    for (Object uuid : idList) {
      System.out.println(uuid);
    }

}
```

Comment: you're welcome. if it was what you were looking for, you can mark it as `accepted` so that other people know this will work before testing it.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb , never use a raw type like below

ArrayList idList = new ArrayList();

If you do so , the compiler will generate a warning , which you should never ignore. Always write the generic parametrised version to avoid such pitfalls

```
ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
```

if you are using JDK10 or above , you an use

```
  var idList = new ArrayList<String>();  // compiler will infer from right handside that its a List<String>
```